# Win32 UI with tabs and buttons

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

I am making a UI library for the fun of it, and decided to use move semantics instead of pointers with new/delete.

Everything is working, but I am not satisfied.

Given this code:

```
void ControlGroup::AddControl(Control&& control) noexcept
{
    if(control.tabstop)
        control.taborder = GetMaxTabOrder() + 1;

    control.SetParent(*parent_control);

    HWND hwnd = control.hwnd;
    control_map.emplace(control.hwnd, std::move(control));

    Control* c = &control_map.at(hwnd);
    tab_map.emplace(c->taborder, c);
}
```

I would like advice for a better technique to add Control* c inside tab_map.

Before going further - Are move semantics really worth the trouble?

The complete related code follows:

**Control.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "../class_macro.hpp"
#include "Window.hpp"
#include <cassert>

class ControlGroup;

struct UserControlCreateInfo {
    SIZE client_size{};
    int control_id{};
    Window::Layout layout{};
    POINT position{};
    int taborder{};
    bool tabstop{true};
    LPCTSTR text{};
    SIZE window_size{};
};

class Control : public Window {
    ControlGroup* control_group;

    friend ControlGroup;

protected:
    int control_id;
    int taborder;
    bool tabstop;

public:
    ENABLE_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR(Control)

    struct ControlCreateInfo {
        LPCTSTR class_name{};
        SIZE client_size{};
        int control_id{};
        DWORD ex_style{};
        HWND hwnd_parent{};
        Layout layout{};
        POINT position{};
        DWORD style{};
        int taborder{};
        bool tabstop{true};
        LPCTSTR text{};
        SIZE window_size{};
    };

    Control(const ControlCreateInfo& cci) noexcept;

protected:
    Control(const UserControlCreateInfo& cci, LPCTSTR class_name, DWORD style = {}, DWORD ex_style = {}) noexcept;

public:
    virtual ~Control() noexcept;

    virtual void SetFocus() noexcept;
    void AddChild(Control&& control) noexcept;

    virtual bool BeforeKeyDown(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wparam) noexcept override;

private:
    void SetParent(const Window& parent_window) noexcept;
};
```

**Control.cpp**

```
#include "Control.hpp"
#include "ControlGroup.hpp"

Control::Control(Control&& other) noexcept :
    Window{std::move(other)},
    control_group{other.control_group},
    control_id{other.control_id},
    taborder{other.taborder},
    tabstop{other.tabstop}
{
    other.control_group = nullptr;
}

Control::Control(const ControlCreateInfo& cci) noexcept :
    Window{{
        .class_name = cci.class_name,
        .client_size = cci.client_size,
        .ex_style = cci.ex_style,
        .hwnd_parent = cci.hwnd_parent,
        .layout = cci.layout,
        .position = cci.position,
        .style = cci.style,
        .text = cci.text,
        .window_size = cci.window_size,
    }},
    control_group{new ControlGroup(this)},
    control_id{cci.control_id},
    taborder{cci.taborder},
    tabstop{cci.tabstop}
{}

Control::Control(const UserControlCreateInfo& cci, LPCTSTR class_name, DWORD style, DWORD ex_style) noexcept :
    Window{{
        .class_name = class_name,
        .client_size = cci.client_size,
        .ex_style = ex_style,
        .layout = cci.layout,
        .position = cci.position,
        .style = style,
        .text = cci.text,
        .window_size = cci.window_size,
    }},
    control_group{new ControlGroup(this)},
    control_id{cci.control_id},
    taborder{cci.taborder},
    tabstop{cci.tabstop}
{}

Control::~Control() noexcept
{
    if(control_group) {
        delete control_group;
        control_group = nullptr;
    }
}

void Control::SetFocus() noexcept
{
    ::SetFocus(hwnd);
}

void Control::AddChild(Control&& control) noexcept
{
    control_group->AddControl(std::move(control));
}

bool Control::BeforeKeyDown(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wparam) noexcept
{
    switch(wparam) {
        case VK_TAB: {
            bool cycle_up = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
            control_group->CycleTab(cycle_up);
            return true;
        }
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            Destroy();
            return true;
    }

    return Window::BeforeKeyDown(hwnd, wparam);
}

void Control::SetParent(const Window& parent_window) noexcept
{
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style | WS_CHILD);
    ::SetParent(hwnd, parent_window.GetHandle());
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, window_size.cx, window_size.cy, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
    Show();
}
```

**ControlGroup.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "Control.hpp"
#include <map>

class ControlGroup {
    const Control* parent_control;
    std::map<HWND, Control> control_map;
    std::multimap<int, Control*> tab_map;

public:
    DISABLE_COPY_AND_MOVE(ControlGroup)

    ControlGroup(const Control* parent_control) noexcept;
    ~ControlGroup() noexcept;

    void AddControl(Control&& control) noexcept;
    void CycleTab(bool cycle_up) noexcept;

private:
    int GetMaxTabOrder() const noexcept;
    Control* FindControlByHandle(HWND control) noexcept;
    Control* FindNextControlInTabOrder(Control* control, bool cycle_up) noexcept;
    void SetFocusToControl(Control* control) noexcept;
    void SetFocusToFirstControl() noexcept;
};
```

**ControlGroup.cpp**

```
#include "ControlGroup.hpp"

ControlGroup::ControlGroup(const Control* parent_control) noexcept :
    parent_control{parent_control} {}

ControlGroup::~ControlGroup() noexcept
{
    parent_control = nullptr;
}

void ControlGroup::AddControl(Control&& control) noexcept
{
    if(control.tabstop)
        control.taborder = GetMaxTabOrder() + 1;

    control.SetParent(*parent_control);

    HWND hwnd = control.hwnd;
    control_map.emplace(control.hwnd, std::move(control));

    Control* c = &control_map.at(hwnd);
    tab_map.emplace(c->taborder, c);
}

void ControlGroup::CycleTab(bool cycle_up) noexcept
{
    HWND focus = GetFocus();
    if(!focus) {
        SetFocusToFirstControl();
        return;
    }

    auto control = FindControlByHandle(focus);
    if(!control) {
        SetFocusToFirstControl();
        return;
    }

    control = FindNextControlInTabOrder(control, cycle_up);
    if(control)
        control->SetFocus();
}

int ControlGroup::GetMaxTabOrder() const noexcept
{
    auto it = tab_map.crbegin();
    if(it != tab_map.crend())
        return it->first;
    return 0;
}

Control* ControlGroup::FindControlByHandle(HWND control) noexcept
{
    auto it = control_map.find(control);
    if(it == control_map.end())
        return nullptr;

    return &it->second;
}

Control* ControlGroup::FindNextControlInTabOrder(Control* control, bool cycle_up) noexcept
{
    if(tab_map.size() == 1)
        return control;

    auto current = tab_map.find(control->taborder);
    if(current == tab_map.end())
        return nullptr;

    if(cycle_up) {
        if(current == tab_map.begin())
            return tab_map.rbegin()->second;

        return std::prev(current)->second;
    }

    auto next = std::next(current);
    if(next == tab_map.end())
        return tab_map.begin()->second;

    return next->second;
}

void ControlGroup::SetFocusToControl(Control* control) noexcept
{
    control->SetFocus();
}

void ControlGroup::SetFocusToFirstControl() noexcept
{
    const auto it = tab_map.cbegin();
    if(it != tab_map.cend())
        SetFocusToControl(it->second);
}
```

**Window.hpp**

```
#pragma once
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>
#include "../class_macro.hpp"
#include "../tstring.hpp"

class Window {
protected:
    HWND hwnd;
    SIZE window_size;
    DWORD style;
    bool active;

public:
    DISABLE_COPY(Window)
    ENABLE_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR(Window)

    static const DWORD DEFAULT_STYLE;

    enum class Layout {
        Custom,
        CenterParent,
        FillParent
    };

    struct WindowCreateInfo {
        LPCTSTR class_name{};
        SIZE client_size{};
        DWORD ex_style{};
        HMENU hwnd_menu{};
        HWND hwnd_parent{};
        Layout layout{};
        POINT position{};
        DWORD style{};
        LPCTSTR text{};
        SIZE window_size{};
    };

    Window(const WindowCreateInfo& wci) noexcept;
    virtual ~Window() noexcept;

    virtual void Show() noexcept;
    virtual void Hide() noexcept;
    virtual bool MessageUpdate() noexcept;
    virtual bool MessageLoop() noexcept;
    virtual void Destroy() noexcept;

    virtual bool OnMouseClick(WPARAM wparam, int x, int y) noexcept;
    virtual bool BeforeKeyDown(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wparam) noexcept;
    virtual bool OnKeyDown(WPARAM wparam) noexcept;

    [[nodiscard]] bool IsDestroyed() const noexcept { return !active; }
    [[nodiscard]] virtual HWND GetHandle() const noexcept { return hwnd; }
    [[nodiscard]] virtual SIZE GetWindowSize() const noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] virtual SIZE GetClientSize() const noexcept;
    [[nodiscard]] virtual tstring GetText() const noexcept;

protected:
    virtual LRESULT WndProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept;

private:
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProcStatic(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept;
    void PrepareWndClass(HINSTANCE hinstance, LPCTSTR class_name) const noexcept;
    void ProcessMessage(const MSG& msg) noexcept;
};

inline SIZE RectToSize(const RECT& rect) noexcept;
```

**Window.cpp**

```
#include "Window.hpp"
#include <cassert>

constexpr LONG DEFAULT_WIDTH = 384;
constexpr SIZE GetDefaultSize(const int size) { return {size, LONG(size / (16 / 9.0))}; }

static LPCTSTR DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME = TEXT("ShigotoShoujinWndClass");
const DWORD Window::DEFAULT_STYLE = WS_SYSMENU | WS_CAPTION | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;

static SIZE GetParentSize(HWND hwnd_parent) noexcept;
static SIZE AdjustWindowSize(SIZE client_size, DWORD style, DWORD ex_style) noexcept;
static POINT CenterWindow(SIZE parent_size, SIZE window_size) noexcept;

Window::Window(Window&& other) noexcept :
    hwnd{other.hwnd},
    window_size{other.window_size},
    style{other.style},
    active{other.active}
{
    other.hwnd = {};
    other.active = false;
}

Window::Window(const WindowCreateInfo& wci) noexcept
{
    HINSTANCE hinstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    POINT position = wci.position;
    LPCTSTR class_name = wci.class_name ? wci.class_name : DEFAULT_CLASS_NAME;

    style = wci.style;
    window_size = wci.window_size;

    bool is_child = wci.style & WS_CHILD;
    assert((is_child && wci.hwnd_parent) || (!is_child && !wci.hwnd_parent));

    if(!style && !wci.class_name)
        style = DEFAULT_STYLE;

    if(wci.hwnd_parent != HWND_DESKTOP)
        style |= WS_CHILD;

    PrepareWndClass(hinstance, class_name);

    switch(wci.layout) {
        case Layout::Custom:
        case Layout::CenterParent:
            if(wci.client_size.cx && wci.client_size.cy)
                window_size = AdjustWindowSize(wci.client_size, style, wci.ex_style);
            else if(!window_size.cx || !window_size.cy)
                window_size = GetDefaultSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH);

            if(wci.layout == Layout::CenterParent)
                position = CenterWindow(GetParentSize(wci.hwnd_parent), window_size);

            break;
        case Layout::FillParent:
            if(!wci.style && wci.hwnd_parent == HWND_DESKTOP)
                style = WS_POPUP;
            position = {};
            window_size = GetParentSize(wci.hwnd_parent);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(wci.ex_style, class_name, wci.text, style, position.x, position.y, window_size.cx, window_size.cy, wci.hwnd_parent, wci.hwnd_menu, hinstance, NULL);
    assert(hwnd);

    active = true;
    SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)(this));
}

Window::~Window() noexcept
{
    Destroy();
}

void Window::Show() noexcept
{
    assert(active);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
}

void Window::Hide() noexcept
{
    assert(active);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
}

bool Window::MessageUpdate() noexcept
{
    assert(active);

    MSG msg;

    while(active && PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        ProcessMessage(msg);

    return active;
}

bool Window::MessageLoop() noexcept
{
    assert(active);

    MSG msg;

    while(active && GetMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0))
        ProcessMessage(msg);

    return active;
}

void Window::Destroy() noexcept
{
    if(hwnd && active) {
        active = false;
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        hwnd = 0;
    }
}

bool Window::OnMouseClick(WPARAM wparam, int x, int y) noexcept
{
    return false;
}

bool Window::BeforeKeyDown(HWND hwnd, WPARAM wparam) noexcept
{
    return false;
}

bool Window::OnKeyDown(WPARAM wparam) noexcept
{
    return false;
}

SIZE Window::GetWindowSize() const noexcept
{
    assert(active);

    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
    return RectToSize(rect);
}

SIZE Window::GetClientSize() const noexcept
{
    assert(active);

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
    return RectToSize(rect);
}

tstring Window::GetText() const noexcept
{
    assert(active);

    size_t max_count = SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
    TCHAR* buffer = new TCHAR[max_count + 1];
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, max_count + 1, (LPARAM)buffer);

    tstring text(buffer);
    delete[] buffer;

    return text;
}

LRESULT Window::WndProc(UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            if(OnMouseClick(wparam, LOWORD(lparam), HIWORD(lparam)))
                return 0;
            break;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if(OnKeyDown(wparam))
                return 0;
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            Destroy();
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Window::WndProcStatic(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) noexcept
{
    Window* self;

    if(msg != WM_NCCREATE && (self = (Window*)(GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA))))
        return self->WndProc(msg, wparam, lparam);

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}

void Window::PrepareWndClass(HINSTANCE hinstance, LPCTSTR class_name) const noexcept
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    if(!GetClassInfoEx(hinstance, class_name, &wc)) {
        wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
        wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = Window::WndProcStatic;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hInstance = hinstance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = class_name;
        wc.hIconSm = NULL;

        RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    }
}

void Window::ProcessMessage(const MSG& msg) noexcept
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);

    if(msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
        if(BeforeKeyDown(msg.hwnd, msg.wParam))
            return;

    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

inline SIZE RectToSize(const RECT& rect) noexcept
{
    return {rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top};
}

static SIZE GetParentSize(HWND hwnd_parent) noexcept
{
    if(hwnd_parent != HWND_DESKTOP) {
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hwnd_parent, &rect);
        return RectToSize(rect);
    } else
        return {GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)};
}

static SIZE AdjustWindowSize(SIZE client_size, DWORD style, DWORD ex_style) noexcept
{
    RECT rect{0, 0, client_size.cx, client_size.cy};
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, style, 0, ex_style);
    return RectToSize(rect);
}

static POINT CenterWindow(SIZE parent_size, SIZE window_size) noexcept
{
    return {
        (parent_size.cx - window_size.cx) >> 1,
        (parent_size.cy - window_size.cy) >> 1};
}
```

Also available in this [repo](https://github.com/ShigotoShoujin/shigoto.shoujin/), but everything needed is shown above.

Comment: Also added Window.hpp / Window.cpp in the post.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/269056/5) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to [edit] and give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### WndProc setup

It's been a while since I've done Windows API stuff, so my memory's kinda fuzzy, but I think there's an issue with how the window procedure is set up in the `Window` class:

`CreateWindowEx` only returns after various calls have already been made to the window procedure. Until it returns, `hwnd` isn't set properly, and `this` isn't passed to the userdata with `SetWindowLongPtr`. So in the meantime we might pass a null `hwnd` to `DefWindowProc`, and we won't call our own `WndProc` function until later than we should.

I think the correct way to solve the issue is to pass `this` as the `lParam` in `CreateWindowEx`. We can retrieve it in the window proc for the `WM_NCCREATE` message, and use it in `SetWindowLongPtr`. At the same time, we set the `hwnd` member to the correct value.

See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20191014-00/?p=102992) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140203-00/?p=1893) for more details and the "correct" way to do things.

---

### Simplify settings structs

There's a lot of shared data between `WindowCreateInfo`, `ControlCreateInfo` and `UserControlCreateInfo`. Perhaps we can split these variables into groups to avoid duplication?

`ControlCreateInfo` adds `control_id`, `taborder` and `tabstop` and removes `hwnd_menu`. `UserControlCreateInfo` removes `hwnd_parent`, `class_name`, `style` and `ex_style`, but they're passed to the constructor as separate parameters anyway.

So perhaps we could use `WindowCreateInfo` throughout the codebase, and add a second parameter for `Control`s:

```
struct ControlCreateInfo {
    int control_id{};
    int taborder{};
    bool tabstop{true};
};

...

Control(WindowCreateInfo const& wci, ControlCreateInfo const& cci) { ... }
```

I'm not sure we need a separate protected constructor for `Control`.

---

### Use plain C++ instead of macros

I admit that I used to use similar macros for move and copy when it was first introduced, but quickly decided that was more trouble than just typing the declarations.

For example, I spent a while thinking there was a bug with how the `control_group` was handled, because I assumed that `ENABLE_MOVE_CONSTRUCTOR` would `= default` the move constructor. Unexpectedly, it's actually just a declaration, and we have the full definition in the .cpp file.

I think it's much clearer to write out the full declaration in the class though: `Control(Control&& other) noexcept;` so people like me don't get confused. It's about the same amount of typing anyway.

---

### Avoid manual memory management

We should use `std::unique_ptr<ControlGroup>` so that we don't have to manually delete it, and we can also use the `= default` move constructor.

---

### `Control` and `ControlGroup`

The `ControlGroup` stores `Controls` by value in the `control_map`, and `Control*`s in the `tab_map`. This is safe, because the `ControlGroup` can ensure that we don't add or remove a `Control` without changing the `tab_map`.

However, that's not the case for the `parent_control`. Moving the owning `Control` will change its location in memory, but the `ControlGroup`'s `parent_control` pointer won't be updated.

It might be reasonable to decide that a `Control` "Is A" `ControlGroup` (every `Control` allocates its own after all), and merge the two classes together. I think it's safe to allow `ControlGroup` to be moved, since moving a `std::map` won't invalidate pointers.

We can keep the functionality separate by having `Control` inherit `ControlGroup`:

```
class Control;

class ControlGroup
{
protected:
    ControlGroup();

    Control* GetOwner();
};

// note: function must be defined in the .cpp file so we have complete knowledge of Control
Control* ControlGroup::GetParent() { return static_cast<Control*>(this); }

class Control : public ControlGroup, public Window { ... };
```

Since our `*this` pointer is always up-to-date, we can get the `Control`, even if it (and the `ControlGroup`) is moved.

As a side-note, we should be able to implement move-assignment for the `Control` class as well as move-construction.

---

### Control insertion

```
HWND hwnd = control.hwnd;
control_map.emplace(control.hwnd, std::move(control));

Control* c = &control_map.at(hwnd);
tab_map.emplace(c->taborder, c);
```

From the linked repo, it looks like you've already found that `emplace` returns an iterator. :)

It's probably worth an `assert`ion or some other check to ensure that adding the control succeeded. (And maybe we should do the insertion before any of the other operations here).

---

### Move semantics and pointers

I think the main issue with using move-semantics here is (as seen above), keeping references (or pointers), up to date. The `ControlGroup` class can ensure that it only uses pointers while a `Control` exists safely on it's `control_map`. Any outside use of `Control` pointers is likely to be unsafe, so we have to use `hwnd`s (or some other id) everywhere else.

If you're happy with this restriction then that's fine. If not, then storing Controls in `unique_ptr`s might be easier. You still have a single point of ownership, but pointers are valid for the entire lifetime of the `Control` instance.

---

### Move assignment

[In response to comments:] The copy and swap idiom is a good way to implement the move-assignment operator. It looks like this for a class `T`:

```
T& T::operator=(T&& other)
{
    T temp (std::move(other)); // use the move constructor to copy from other

    using std::swap;
    swap(m_var_1, temp.m_var_1); // swap each member variable between this and temp
    swap(m_var_2, temp.m_var_2);

    return *this;
}
```

We could provide a `void swap(T& other)` member function on our class to encapsulate all the swapping if we have many variables, and just call `swap(temp)`.

If we wanted to, we could unify it with the copy constructor by providing a single `operator=` like so.

```
T& T::operator=(T other)
{
    swap(temp); // use the swap member function we defined
    return *this;
}
```

This is safe for self-assignment, so we don't need to check for it. (Although we could check for self-assignment and avoid the swapping, note that self-assignment is very rare. By doing the check we make the "normal" (non-self-assignment) case slower! So we just don't check).

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed and informative answer. Receiving feedback is a great way to give weight to particular a design choice while there are so many ways of achieving the same 'visual' result.

I did not realize that WndProc would be called more then once with WM_NCCREATE before CreateWindowsEx returns.

Comment: On the duplicate structs, they were an attempts to avoid having structs based on other structs, which makes the c++20 named initializer less beautiful, having to use extra {} for each base class. But indeed no need to inherit if we just pass WindowCreateInfo along with ControlCreateInfo.

Comment: Agreed on macro, they obfuscate the code.

Comment: Also agreed on Control being A ControlGroup. This should resolve the issue with the existance of "friend ControlGroup;" in Control.hpp. Having to use "friend" seems like a bad smell.

Comment: The parent_control not being updated might just be the answer to the bug that I was having yesterday while implementing ColorControl, a color picker.

Comment: Indeed for map::emplace, I've found the solution meanwhile : )

Comment: When you say that the default move constructor could be used if std::unique_ptr is used to manage ControlGroup*, doesn't the default move ctor only copy values and does not clear them? And this would be ok because the moved unique_ptr would just be internally flagged as not containing ptr anymore? More reading needs to be done. Being able to use the default move ctor / assign would be very nice.

Comment: In a move assigment operator we have to also check for self reference and destroy *this before proceeding, would it be fine to manually call our own destructor with this::~ClassName();, meaning that the destructor could be called twice but not on the same internal values? Or should a "Destroy" function be made, and called from both the destructor and the move assignment? Many thanks.

Comment: @ShigotoShoujin Yep. Moving from a std::unique_ptr is guaranteed to leave the `unique_ptr` empty (it effectively calls `release()` on it): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D

Comment: @ShigotoShoujin You shouldn't manually call the destructor in the move assignment operator. Having a "Destroy" function would work. Even better would be to use the "copy and swap" idiom. That method uses the destructor to do cleanup, and ensures safety, even for self-assignment.

Comment: On "Avoid manual memory management", in this particular case the default move cannot be used, because at that point ControlGroup is declared but not defined, which lead to error "can't delete an incomplete type". Other than that, it is now an unique_ptr in the feature/color_control branch :)

Comment: The std::map will need to store pointers to Control instead of values, otherwise it does not handle inheritance and objects derived from Control will not be stored correctly.

This defeat the whole purpose of going with value type.